# Electron Forge osxNotarize hangs on notarytool submit

Tags: electron-forge, notarize, electron-notarize

I'm able to sign my apps but notarization hangs on the Finalizing Package step.

Here's my forge config for when I run the package command. Ive checked that the env variables are there.

```
packagerConfig: {
    ...
    osxSign: {
      'identity': "Developer ID Application: <MyCompany> (<My Code>)",
      'hardened-runtime': true,
      'gatekeeper-assess': false,
      'entitlements': 'entitlements.plist',
      'entitlements-inherit': 'entitlements.plist',
    },
    osxNotarize: {
      tool: 'notarytool',
      appleId: process.env.APPLE_ID,
      appleIdPassword: process.env.APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD,
      teamId: process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID,
    },
    ...
```

If I remove the notarize step then packaging doesn't hang and I assume the app is signed. I left this running for 8 hrs and it was still finalizing.

It seems to be hanging at this step:

```
electron-notarize:notarytool zip succeeded, attempting to upload to Apple +1m
  electron-notarize:spawn spawning cmd: xcrun args: [
  'notarytool',
  'submit',
  '/var/folders/4g/p6tq8s_j4tqf78675mcggp8m0000gn/T/electron-notarize-TYQUzu/MYAPP.zip',
  '--apple-id',
  '*********',
  '--password',
  '*********',
  '--team-id',
  '*********',
  '--wait',
  '--output-format',
  'json'
] opts: {} +1ms
```

Running this command directly also produces no output and seems to hang.

MYAPP.zip is 0.3gb.

What steps could I be missing?